How TGetBaseTypeHelper template works in unreal engine
Recently, I'm reading code of render system in the unreal engine5.3. I feel very confused about some of reflection code in shader. Here is an shader example in AnisotropyRendering.cpp.
class FAnisotropyVS : public FMeshMaterialShader
{
public:
    DECLARE_SHADER_TYPE(FAnisotropyVS, MeshMaterial);

    static bool ShouldCompilePermutation(const FMeshMaterialShaderPermutationParameters& Parameters)
    {
        // Compile if supported by the hardware.
        const bool bIsFeatureSupported = IsFeatureLevelSupported(Parameters.Platform, ERHIFeatureLevel::SM5);

        return 
            bIsFeatureSupported && 
            IsAnisotropyPassCompatible(Parameters.Platform, Parameters.MaterialParameters) &&
            FMeshMaterialShader::ShouldCompilePermutation(Parameters);
    }

    FAnisotropyVS() = default;
    FAnisotropyVS(const ShaderMetaType::CompiledShaderInitializerType& Initializer)
        : FMeshMaterialShader(Initializer)
    {}
};

After expanding DECLARE_SHADER_TYPE macro, I found some piece of code
private:
  using InternalBaseType = typename TGetBaseTypeHelper<FAnisotropyVS>::Type;
  template <typename InternalType>
  static void InternalInitializeBases(FTypeLayoutDesc &TypeDesc) {
    TInitializeBaseHelper<InternalType, InternalBaseType>::Initialize(TypeDesc);
  };
public:
  using DerivedType = FAnisotropyVS;
  static constexpr ETypeLayoutInterface ::Type InterfaceType =
      ETypeLayoutInterface ::NonVirtual;
  template <int Counter> struct InternalLinkType {
    ;
    static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) void
    Initialize(FTypeLayoutDesc &TypeDesc) {}
  };

The confused thing is, compiler tells me InternalBaseType is actually a type alias of FMeshMaterialShader, but it seems to me that InternalBaseType should be a alias of FAnisotropyVS.
TGetBaseTypeHelper template defined in MemoryLayout.h
template<typename T>
struct TGetBaseTypeHelper
{
    UE_STATIC_ONLY(TGetBaseTypeHelper);
    template<typename InternalType> static typename InternalType::DerivedType Test(const typename InternalType::DerivedType*);
    template<typename InternalType> static void Test(...);

    using Type = decltype(Test<T>(nullptr));
};

Because FAnisotropyVS::DerivedType is just FAnisotropyVS. I can't see why InternalBaseType is a alias of FMeshMaterialShader(base type)
I will very appreciate it if someone can enlighten me what happens here. Though this is a very small implementation problem and nobody cares...

In class FMeshMaterialShader
class RENDERER_API FMeshMaterialShader : public FMaterialShader
{
    DECLARE_TYPE_LAYOUT(FMeshMaterialShader, NonVirtual);
};

This macro will be expanded into some code and a piece of it like this
public:
    using DerivedType = FMeshMaterialShader;

now the DerivedType is FMeshMaterialShader.
when class FAnisotropyVS inherits class FMeshMaterialShader.
class FAnisotropyVS looks like this
class FAnisotropyVS : public FMeshMaterialShader
{
   // The declaration of FMeshMaterialShader
public:
   using DerivedType = FMeshMaterialShader;
   //... some code

   // The declaration of FAnisotropyVS its own
public:
    DECLARE_SHADER_TYPE(FAnisotropyVS, MeshMaterial);
};

Now when DECLARE_SHADER_TYPE(FAnisotropyVS, MeshMaterial); expand like this
private:
  using InternalBaseType = typename TGetBaseTypeHelper<FAnisotropyVS>::Type;
  // Some code ...
public:
  using DerivedType = FAnisotropyVS;
  

The DerivedType is still FMeshMaterialShader, because using DerivedType = FAnisotropyVS; is after this piece of code.
So InternalBaseType in FAnisotropyVS is alias of FMeshMaterialShader

That's exactly what I missed! But I never see this usage before and the implementation is too tricky for me. I think there should be more natural ways to find the base class...
